# I'm having problems baking multiple objects

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

I have a model that's textured and I want to port it into a game engine. The catch is that the model has around 21 different objects. Following a baking tutorial by Grant Abbit, I followed the steps of bake multiple objects with separate textures into one texture, but every time I hit bake, it bakes onto the old texture using the new UV instead of baking it onto the bake texture. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. I've tried renaming the UVs, I've looked over every object at least 4 times now and whatever I do, the outcome remains the same. [image: Heres a photo of the screen I would see just before baking. If you can spot anything, please let me know. If you need the file for further info, just let me know as well.]

Comment: I don't completely understand what you mean. Look into Easy baker for baking multiple objects. Otherwise, copy them and join  them and use selected to active in the baking settings and make sure none of your UVs are overlapping. You only need one UV channel for porting into a game engine unless you are using another one for lightmap UVs.